# Unable to log in to CDK created Amazon MQ (RabbitMQ) web console

Tags: rabbitmq, aws-cdk, amazon-mq

When creating a publicly accessible Amazon MQ instance (with RabbitMQ under the hood), I can easily log in to the web console.

However when creating an MQ instance using the same settings and credentials through CDK I can't log in to the web console. The only response from the RabbitMQ service is

```json
{
    "error": "not_authorised",
    "reason": "Login failed"
}
```

The Cloudwatch logs indicate that the user was created, but also warn that the user tried to log in using invalid credentials:

```
2021-07-02 14:20:54.867 [info] <0.1474.0> Created user 'admin'
2021-07-02 14:20:55.587 [info] <0.1481.0> Successfully set user tags for user 'admin' to [administrator]
2021-07-02 14:20:56.295 [info] <0.1488.0> Successfully set permissions for 'admin' in virtual host '/' to '.*', '.*', '.*'
2021-07-02 14:26:14.529 [warning] <0.1639.0> HTTP access denied: user 'admin' - invalid credentials
```

The construction of the Broker looks like this:

```js
private createMessageBroker(vpc: Vpc, stage: Stage) {
        const password: Secret = new Secret(this, 'BrokerAdminPassword', {
            generateSecretString: { excludePunctuation: true },
            description: 'Password for the Message Broker User',
        });
        const user: CfnBroker.UserProperty = {
            consoleAccess: true,
            username: 'admin',
            password: password.toString(),
        };

        new CfnBroker(this, 'TaskMessageBroker', {
            autoMinorVersionUpgrade: true,
            brokerName: 'MessageBroker',
            deploymentMode: 'SINGLE_INSTANCE',
            engineType: 'RABBITMQ',
            engineVersion: '3.8.11',
            hostInstanceType: 'mq.t3.micro',
            publiclyAccessible: true,
            users: [user],
            logs: { general: true },
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following instead when instantiating your `UserProperty`

```
const user: CfnBroker.UserProperty = {
  consoleAccess: true,
  username: 'admin',
  password: password.secretValue.toString(),
}
```